# Conditional form input field types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Rails 2.3.11

I would like to use a text_field to input data under one condition, otherwise using a selection box.  Right now, my code looks like this:

**views/posters/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for @poster, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %> - We're not going to enlarge it for you, so please upload the biggest copy you can!<br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %><br />
  </p>


    <p>
    <% if current_user.admin? && params[:event_id] && !current_user.events.find_by_id(params[:event_id]) && Event.find_by_id(params[:event_id]) %>
      <%= f.label "Event ID" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :event_id, :value => params[:event_id] %>
    <% else  %>
      <%= f.label :event_id %><br />
      <%= f.select :event_id, @events, :selected => params[:event_id].to_i %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/posters_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @poster = Poster.new

    current_user ||= User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
    @events = [["Don't attach to an event", '']]
    current_user.events.each {|event| @events << [event.title, event.id]}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @poster }
    end
end
```

**Error message**:  http://cl1p.net/halp

**How can I use two different types of form input fields for the same parameter (but each under a different condition, not simultaneously)?**

**Update:** I think the problem stems from the issue of Rails putting the previously-submitted information back into their respective input fields.  This explains why no tantrum is thrown when a file that passes all the validation tests (that is, a PNG less than 3 MB), but breaks down when nothing (or anything that doesn't meet that condition) is attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't understand why you are manually setting the values on the text box and select box. Usually, Rails does this for you, but without the form definition, I can't tell if you really need to do this.

Even then, given the information, I think it's safe to say that what you need is this:

```
f.text_field :event_id
...
f.select :event_id, @events
```

This ought to work for what you intend to do. I'm not sure what it has to do with the submitting of a file, but yes you are right about the previously-submitted part. The unexpected nil stems from this:

```
params[:event_id].to_i
```

Unless you are setting this parameter entry manually inside your controller, you will not be able to cast it to an integer if it is nil. If you go with using the basic form helper calls this goes away.

Comment: When I looked into it further, it had nothing directly to do with the attachment of a file - that was only the deciding factor for whether the creation of a new Poster was successful... or returned to the "new" page for a correction, causing the error.

Would that new `f.select` also automatically select the event whose ID was passed as a URL argument?

Comment: That did not work.  By splitting the Rails code onto multiple lines, I've determined that the unexpected nil has to do with the `:event_id` adjacent to `f.select`.

Comment: You did not mention that event_id was passed as a URL argument, but yes f.select does indeed automatically select the event id in such a case.

Comment: If you post your form_for call, and your controller action code, and maybe the actual exception being thrown it would be easier to help you.

Comment: The error appears to be in the 'new' view when displayed by the 'create' action. Did you create the @events instance variable in the create action as well? Otherwise, post your create action code.

Comment: You were right.  Once I put the @event definition in "create" and "update" (in addition to "new" and "edit"), everything worked smoothly; thank you!